# How do you decide a new datum?

Tags: datum, geodesy, geodetic

How do you decide datum size (axies a & b) and datum position relative to WGS84 (dx,dy,dz,rx,ry,rz) for a country if you were to create a new datum best fit for the country? 
Example, is datum surface needed to be below the lowest elevation always or can be placed at average elevation of the country topography..etc?